# populating spiner2 from 1 and being able to select spinner2 value and toast selection

Tags: android, arrays, string, spinner, bind

struggling with this so  heres what I have.

Spinner 1 array.

```
 <!--for spinner 1-->
 <string-array name="Manu_array">
 <item>Manu 1xsd</item>
 <item>Manu 2xrsd</item>
 <item>Manu 3x4rsd</item>
 </string-array>
```

Spinner 2 arrays.

```
<!--for spinner 2-->

<string-array name="Manu 1xsd">
<item>a1</item>
<item>a2</item>
<item>a3</item>
<item>a4</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="Manu 2xrsd">
 <item>bg 1</item>
 <item>bg 2</item>
 </string-array>

 <string-array name="Manu 3x4rsd">
 <item>z1</item>
 <item>z2</item>
 <item>zd4</item>
 <item>xs5</item>
 <item>fg34</item>
 </string-array>
```

So spinner 1 I would select "Manu 3x4rsd" then spinner 2 "xs5" I would Toast "Manu 3x4rsd " + "xs5"

My Java code for Spinner 1 selection:

```
final Spinner[] spinner1 = {(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1)};

 // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
 R.array.Manu_array, R.layout.textview);

  spinner1[0].setAdapter(adapter);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  // Apply the adapter to the spinner
  spinner1[0].setAdapter(adapter);

  spinner1[0].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                               int arg2, long arg3) {

        int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
        // storing string resources into Array
        Manu= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Manu_array);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " + Manu[index],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

My Java Code for Spinner 2 selection

```
final  Spinner Spinner2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
Spinner1[0].setOnItemSelectedListener(new adapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
 int arrayId = 0;
 switch (position) {//get array id according to selected position
 case 0:
 arrayId = R.array.Manu_1xsd_array;
 break;
 case 1:
 arrayId = R.array.Manu_2xrsd;
 break;
 case 2:
 arrayId = R.array.Manu_3x4rsd.array;
 break;
 };

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterL =   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(settings.this, arrayId, R.layout.textview);
Spinner1.setAdapter(adapterL);

String Spinner1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " + Spinner1,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // do nothing
        }
```

The issue is whilst I can see the values populated in spinner 2 and scroll through them and it appears I can select them, I have no code to do anything on selecting them and generate the toast. I have tried to create a listener within the spinner but I am unable to do anything to get it to function as desired.

So I suspect I am going about tackling the problem in completely the wrong way.

Once I can toast the spinner 1 and spinner 2 selected values I should be able to combine them to read from a list of strings to combine them to make a command.

wanted to use spinners for visual effect rather than have a great big list to scroll through just to select the values required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code populates the second spinner according to the selected value from the first spinner, and displays a toast when an item from the second spinner is selected.

```
        final Spinner s1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
        final Spinner s2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Manu_array, R.layout.textview);

        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int arrayId = 0;
                switch (position) {//get array id according to selected position
                    case 0:
                        arrayId = R.array.Manu_1xsd_array;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        arrayId = R.array.Manu_2xrsd;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        arrayId = R.array.Manu_3x4rsd.array;
                        break;
                }
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, arrayId, R.layout.textview);
                s2.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String msg = s1.getSelectedItem().toString() + s2.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks again, obviously I was making things overly complex, works a treat had to change this, to settings.this, working like a charm, thank you very much.